# how to copy the text from text edit into a string variable?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

i am trying to copy the text I enter into the text edit and store it into a string variable.
I have written the following code but it shows 'python has stopped working'

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtWidgets,QtCore
import sys

class GUI(QtWidgets.QWidget):
     def __init__(self):
        super(GUI,self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        review = QtWidgets.QLabel('Review')
        reviewEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        grid.addWidget(review, 3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(reviewEdit, 3, 1, 5, 1)
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.setGeometry(300,300,350,300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Sentiment Analysis')

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("OK")         
        grid.addWidget(button)
        button.clicked.connect(self.copyText)
        self.show()

    def copyText(self):
        reviewEdit.setText("text")
        print(text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = GUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

The program stops working because of a `NameError` in the `copyText()` method. The `reviewEdit` variable doesn't exit in that scope, so you can't reference it.

The way to fix this is to make all the child widgets attributes of the main class - then you can access them later using `self`:

```
class GUI(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI,self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.review = QtWidgets.QLabel('Review')
        self.reviewEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        grid.addWidget(self.review, 3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.reviewEdit, 3, 1, 5, 1)
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.setGeometry(300,300,350,300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Sentiment Analysis')

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("OK")
        grid.addWidget(self.button)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.copyText)
        self.show()

    def copyText(self):
        # self.reviewEdit.setText("text")
        text = self.reviewEdit.toPlainText()
        print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should make reviewEdit a member of GUI class. Like this:

```
self.reviewEdit = QtGui.QTextEdit()
```

next, in addBold(self), you get the text like this:

```
text = str(self.reviewEdit.toPlainText())
```